# Не занимать стать

Tags: этимология

Регулярно при виде вывески "Место кондуктора не занимать" приходит в голову продолжение "стать" (это еще не вопрос)

Откуда взялось это сочетание "не занимать стать"? Может, это остаток какой-то древней формы глагола? И к чему это выражение может применяться: только к уму (Ума не занимать стать) или к чему-то еще?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

~6. стать, всегда вслед за неопр., имеющим при себе отрицание. Выражение уверенности в общем позитивном или негативном смысле высказывания. Трудиться ему не привыкать стать (т. е. он привык, привычен к труду). Силы ему не занимать стать (т. е. он достаточно силен). Мне его не уговаривать стать (т. е. не буду, не собираюсь уговаривать). Пахарю работы не занимать стать. Для тягости родин жениху не отказывать стать (посл.).

(Ожегов)

Здесь "стать" - глагол несовершенного вида, парный к "становиться".
В принципе он имеет подобное вспомогательное (модальное?) значение и в других случаях: "он стал читать", но здесь некоторая непривычная современному языку конструкция с отрицанием инфинитива. 
Не считаю, что данный случай надо относить к усилению. Исторически это обычная грамматика.

> Может, это остаток какой-то древней формы глагола?

Не "формы глагола", форма-то вполне современна. Да и вообще не о форме речь, а о содержании, т.е. функциональном наполнении.
Как сказал уже, это рудимент грамматической конструкции с использованием глагола в качестве вспомогательного.

Comment: Я дал ссылку на Ожегова. К нему все вопросы.
Вы же источник своих откровений не разглашаете, вот вам придется отвечать ха все нестыковки вашего тектса.

Comment: >В котором месте нестыковки? В вашем воображении?    

Ну зачем сразу так грубо?!  
Нестыковки имеенно в том, что вы ставите себе в заслугу. В отнесении конструкции к усилительным. У Ожегова этого слова нет.